# Example of $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ that is injective, $C^\infty$, but not immersion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

I have examples from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ already. Can someone give me at least one example from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take

$$ F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ f(x,y)= (x^3,y^3).$$

This function is real-analytic, bijective and not an immersion, as

$$ D_{(0,0)} F=0. $$

Added: Note that the inverse of $F$ is

$$ F^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ F^{-1}(u,v) = (u^{1/3}, v^{1/3}),$$

which is continuous. Thus, $F$ is a homeomorphism and therefore, open and closed. Hence, $F$ is an example of an open map, that is not a submersion (again this fails at the origin).

Comment: Thank you! Have you a simple example like this of an open smooth map $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that is not submersion? (an example different of $(x, y) \mapsto (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$)

Comment: @Filburt: The same map is not a submersion: A linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension is injective if and only if surjective.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang is it open?

Comment: @Filburt I edited my answer to show why this holds.